# Signing POM file with maven-publish plugin

Tags: gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl, maven-publish

I try to upload an artifact into Nexus using the `maven-publish` plugin.
Almost all goes well, only one problem I couldn't find solution: the generated POM file is not signed.

Here is my code snippet:

```kotlin
plugins {
    maven
    `maven-publish`
    id("signing")
    id("org.jetbrains.dokka") version "1.4.10.2"
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}


group = "my.group"
version = "1.0.0"


tasks {
    val sourcesJar by creating(Jar::class) {
        archiveClassifier.set("sources")
        from(sourceSets.main.get().allSource)
    }

    val javadocJar by creating(Jar::class) {
        dependsOn.add(dokkaJavadoc)
        archiveClassifier.set("javadoc")
        from(dokkaJavadoc)
    }

    artifacts {
        archives(sourcesJar)
        archives(javadocJar)
        archives(jar)
    }
}


@Suppress("UnstableApiUsage")
signing {
    useGpgCmd()
    sign(configurations.archives.get())
}




@Suppress("UnstableApiUsage")
publishing {
    repositories {
        maven {
            val releasesRepoUrl = "https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/"
            val snapshotsRepoUrl = "https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/snapshots/"
            url = uri(if (version.toString().endsWith("SNAPSHOT")) snapshotsRepoUrl else releasesRepoUrl)
            credentials {
                username=project.properties["ossrhUser"].toString()
                password=project.properties["ossrhPassword"].toString()
            }
        }
    }
    publications {
        create<MavenPublication>("maven") {
            groupId = "my.group"
            artifactId = "my-lib"
            version = "1.0.0"

            pom {
                name.set("my-lib")
                description.set("desc")
                url.set("...")

                licenses {
                    license {
                        name.set("The Apache License, Version 2.0")
                        url.set("http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt")
                    }
                }
                developers {
                    developer {
                        id.set("Balage1551")
                        name.set("Balazs Vissy")
                        email.set("...")
                    }
                }
                scm {
                    connection.set("...")
                    developerConnection.set("...")
                    url.set("...")
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

When I run `publish` all goes well, the signed jars are uploaded, but the verification fails with missing ASC file for POM.

Earlier, in gradle 4, when I used `maven` and Groovy, I was able to add to my code:

```
beforeDeployment { MavenDeployment deployment -> signing.signPom(deployment) }
```

to my uploadArchives task.

How can I do it with Kotlin DSL and with the publishing structure?

Comment: What version of Gradle are you currently using?

Comment: @FranciscoMateo: 6.5

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete answer, because it doesn't answer my original question, but this is a working workaround. I switched back to `maven` and used the `Upload` task:

```
    named<Upload>("uploadArchives") {
        val releasesRepoUrl = "https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/"
        val snapshotsRepoUrl = "https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/snapshots/"
        val ossrhUser = project.ext.properties["ossrhUser"].toString()
        val ossrhPassword = project.ext.properties["ossrhPassword"].toString()

        repositories {

            withConvention(MavenRepositoryHandlerConvention::class) {
                mavenDeployer {
                    beforeDeployment {
                        signing.signPom(this)
                    }

                    withGroovyBuilder {
                        "repository"("url" to releasesRepoUrl) {
                            "authentication"("userName" to ossrhUser, "password" to ossrhPassword)
                        }
                        "snapshotRepository"("url" to snapshotsRepoUrl) {
                            "authentication"("userName" to ossrhUser, "password" to ossrhPassword)
                        }
                    }

                    pom.project {
                        withGroovyBuilder {
                           // building up POM in groovy way, awful, but works
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Example 8 of the Gradle Maven Publish Plugin page should contain a solution: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html

Instead of `sign(configurations.archives.get())`, you should use `sign(publishing.publications["maven"])`.